# Umbraco + mvc page redirect with data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, umbraco, umbraco6

I want to redirect to other Umbraco page with model data.

Currently i am just redirecting to other Umbraco page but not with model data.

```
 public ActionResult CNOReplacement(MasterViewModel Model)
        {
            ViewBag.TestData = "Testing ViewBag data passing !!";
            return RedirectToUmbracoPage(1098);   
        }
```

Even i have tried by passing viewmodel but that is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get any solution but have done this using an alternate way,

I have used HttpContext Session Variable to Get Data on Each Umbraco Page.

In controller Action I have created one session

```
Session["MasterViewModel"]=new MasterViewModel();
```

And when redirecting to other Umbraco page using below code:

```
public ActionResult CNOReplacement(MasterViewModel Model)
        {
            return RedirectToUmbracoPage(1098);   
        }
```

And in View we are getting Session Variable as::

```
@inherits Proj.ViewModel.MasterViewModel
@{var PerviousPageModel= Session["MasterViewModel"] as MasterViewModel}
```

Comment: Spent two days trying make this exact scenario work in Umbraco 7.6.3. I finally came to this exact same solution on my own. The only reason I came accross this is because of a google search trying to figure out if there was a best practice for this scenario.  IMHO, this is it!  Just make sure to delete the session variable when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

`[HttpGet]`
`public ActionResult AAA()`
`{`
`GameModel model = new GameModel() { Id = 10 };`
`return RedirectToAction("BBB", "Game", model);`
`}`

`public ActionResult BBB(GameModel model)`
`{`
`return View();`
`}`
[image]>

Comment: I want to redirect to Umbraco page so that i can use its umbraco templates and Macros.

Comment: Use get parameters as public ActionResult method(string param1, int param2,...). And call domain/contollerName/ActionName?param1=value1&param2=value2&...

Comment: @Narek, this is an anti-pattern and frowned upon in Umbraco. Besides, it doesn't work when you include the base of RenderModel in your model - as you should.